# "here's our app as it currently stands"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

what's the meaning of this sentence?
 "**here's our app as it currently stands**"
Is it mean : our app is still here or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+it+stands , this means "as something is now".

Perhaps with larger context or couple more sentences we can explain it to you clearer.

Comment: Quite right, but I will add that "currently" in the given example suggests that there may be future developments; they are emphasising the *current* state of the app.

Comment: Yes. I'd paraphrase it as, "Here is our app **in its current version**." I'd also probably assume that the app is under development, and this _as-it-stands_ version is not complete.

Comment: Let's take another approach. First start to say "Here is our app". Does it change your meaning? If it does, what about "Here is our current app" or "Here is our latest app"? and move on from there.

Answer (score 0):

In programming "**as it currently stands**", as J.R. correctly commented means "**in its current state (version or build)**". The dictionary meaning that [**Oxford**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as_it_stands) gives is "**in its present condition**"

The [Free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+it+stands) gives this meaning "**at this time; as it is now**"